# Android Facebook Login Get DisplayName

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook Sdk for Login into my application. After successfully login i have to call graph api for that particular user for getting Email address of that user.Is there any way for getting Email address and his Display name in success Login response.

This is my code i am calling graph API after successfully login.

```
GraphRequest.newMeRequest(result.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response)
        {
            if (response.getError() != null) 
            {
                // handle error
            } 
            else
            {
                String email = object.optString("email");
                String id = object.optString("id");
                facebookID = id;
                Log.i("Log","email : " + email);
                Log.i("Log","id : " + id);
            }
        }
    }).executeAsync();
```

Comment: Can you see the logcat output for email and id? or it doesn't get called at all? Did you initialized the facebook sdk? Have you overriden the onActivityResult method?

Comment: Yes i have overriden the onActivityResult method and called callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); it will call my onSuccess(LoginResult) method. In this parameter i am only able to get AccessToken,  Set of GrantedPermissions and DeniedPermissions.

Comment: If you make Log output outside of if-else statements, do they occur? I had a problem with getting the user info aswell and the solution that helped me was having onActivityResult on my ParentFragment, because I used Login in DialogFragment

Comment: Please read my question. I don't want to call graph api i want Email address and display name in LoginResult. Is it Possible or not?

Comment: No, I don't think so. You can get name and id with `Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile()`

Comment: OK, Is there any way to get display name via graph api. In this link www.facebook.com/himanshN display name is himanshN

Comment: Here is the [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph) of JSON you get from Graph API, so no, I think you can only get ID and name

Answer (score 1):

You can find the different parameters to get in this link [Facebook Graph-api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user).
Try this code

```
 private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(
                            JSONObject object,
                            GraphResponse response) {
                        Log.v("LoginActivity", response.getRawResponse());
                        Log.v("AccessToken", AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken());
                    }

                });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,birthday");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException e) {

    }
};
```

and please don't forget to override the onActivityResult as follows for example

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

Comment: I mentioned in the question that i don't want to call graph api because Facebook Sdk Internally called this and make a Object of Profile Model class. And i want to get Email, DisplayName in LoginResult Model object class. I hope now you understood.

Answer (score 0):

Try this after login into Facebook:

```
Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile;
String name = profile.getName();
```